# Custom File Formats and storing file related meta-data in my Qt Desktop Application

Tags: c++, qt, file, metadata

I have developed a `Qt` Application (in `C++`) which requires a custom file format `.tst`. It's basically a `csv` format with it's first line storing meta data regarding the file and after that there are `x` and `y` comma separated values.

For example,

```
tv,ca,1
440, 0.000000
441, 0.000000
442, 0.000000
443, 0.000000
444, 0.000000
445, 3.573799
446, 3.573799
447, 2.695069
448, 2.695069
```

The first `string` value in the first line denotes sequencing of meta data. Each character in the first string in the first line denotes the information at a particular position in the comma separated values.

The `t` character denotes that second string in the comma separated values denote the type of the data being stored `ca` in the file. The `v` character denotes that the third string in the comma separated values denote the version of the file format `1`. I can extend and add more characters in the first string and corresponding append the values by separating them with a comma in the first line.

I was wondering Is there any way so that I can stores my meta data in such a way that it doesn't appear in the file content when opened with text editors? I know there is some meta data associated with every file like it's time of creation, last modification time stamp, permissions.

Is there any cross-platform method to store my meta data along with file's meta data?

Even if you have some other better way to store my meta-data, please do mention that in comments or your answers.

Comment: While I don't know if there's a truly cross-platform solution to what you're asking, simply putting the meta information in a seperate file should always work

Comment: But maintaining two files for the data will be difficult.

Comment: Sure. The easiest way, though, would be just living with having metadata in the first line.